# How to get the US population for every year Wolfram has data on?

Tags: curated-data

I know I can use

```
Ctrl = us population
```

to get an estimate for the current US population. I also know

```
== us pollution
```

gives me a few plots showing the US population over time.
One of the plots is the following:
[image]
But how can I get the data used to make the above graphic?

Comment: You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> + "us population time series" to get the Wolfram Language code used by Wolfram Alpha to generate the time series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily reproduce the graphics with

```
DateListPlot[
 CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", All}]["Path"] /. Quantity[a_, _] :> a/10^6.,
 AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

The underlying data being

```
pop = CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", All}]["Path"]
```

`All` stands for "all available years". You can limit the years by replacing `All` with f.e. `{1900, 2016}`.

To see the last year available:

```
pop[[-1]] /. {a_, b_} :> {First@DateList@a, b}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `DateListPlot[CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", All}], AspectRatio -> 1/4, Filling -> Bottom, GridLines -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {# 1*^-6 &, # 1*^6 &}]`

Answer (score 8):

You may use the [Knowledge Representation & Access](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/KnowledgeRepresentationAndAccess.html) guide.

Query the [`CountryData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html) `"Population"` [`EntityProperty`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityProperty.html) for its `"Qualifiers"` and `"QualifierValues"`.

```
EntityValue["Country", "Population", "Qualifiers"]
```

> ```
> {"Age", "CitizenshipStatus", "Date", "Gender", "HispanicOrigin",
>  "MarginOfError", "Percent", "Race", "TwoOrMore", "UrbanRural"}
> ```

Notice that there is a `"Date"` qualifier. Valid `"QualifierValues"` can be returned with `EntityValue["Country", "Population", "QualifierValues"]`.

Using this information we can query the `"UnitedStates"` `"Country"` entity using the `CountryData` function. The [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html) function could also be used on a `"Country"` [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html).

```
ts = CountryData["UnitedStates", EntityProperty["Country", "Population", {"Date" -> All}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This returns a [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) object that appears to contain forecasts as well as historic data.  With `ts` the dates can be returned with `ts["Dates"]` and the dates and values with `ts["DatePath"]`.

```
ts["Dates"] // Short
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ts["DatePath"] // Short
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Thankfully, [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) understands `TimeSeries`. With a rescaling to millions;

```
DateListPlot[ts/10^6, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/4, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Filling -> Bottom]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: `CountryData["UnitedStates",  EntityProperty["Country", "Population", {"Date" -> All}]]` gives me (V10) only the last year (2014). Maybe you could clarify which parts of your solution are V11-specific?

Comment: @eldo I uninstalled my v10 versions a while ago so can't comment on that at the moment.  However, it is entity framework which should reside on WRI servers so I am surprised that you get a different outcome in a different version.  Calls must be version specific or perhaps v10 had a bug that has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done as follows.

```
Table[{j, CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", j}]}, {j, 1950,2014}]
```

> {{1950,151325800people},{1951,154287000people},{1952,156954000people},{1953,159565000people},{1954,162391000people},{1955,165275000people},{1956,168221000people},{1957,171274000people},{1958,174141000people},{1959,177073000people},{1960,179323200people},{1961,183691000people},{1962,186538000people},{1963,189242000people},{1964,191889000people},{1965,194303000people},{1966,196560000people},{1967,198712000people},{1968,200706000people},{1969,202677000people},{1970,209463865people},{1971,211355529people},{1972,213250350people},{1973,215164616people},{1974,217113584people},{1975,219108358people},{1976,221161377people},{1977,223274855people},{1978,225436004people},{1979,227624232people},{1980,229825004people},{1981,232035086people},{1982,234261242people},{1983,236510688people},{1984,238794274people},{1985,241119752people},{1986,243495805people},{1987,245920994people},{1988,248381577people},{1989,250857751people},{1990,253339097people},{1991,255807342people},{1992,258275919people},{1993,260803255people},{1994,263468979people},{1995,266323717people},{1996,269393632people},{1997,272643340people},{1998,275986072people},{1999,279300030people},{2000,282496310people},{2001,285544778people},{2002,288467308people},{2003,291290823people},{2004,294063120people},{2005,296820296people},{2006,299564470people},{2007,302284564people},{2008,304989064people},{2009,307686729people},{2010,310383948people},{2011,313232044people},{2012,316265537people},{2013,319330342people},{2014,322422965people}}

Comment: `CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", {1950, 2015}}]` will yield a `TimeSeries[]` that can be easily fed into `DateListPlot[]`. `CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", {1950, 2015}}] @ "DatePath"` will return a conventional list instead of a `TimeSeries[]`.

Comment: @J.M: That was answered what was asked.

Comment: Using version 10.0 on a Mac, CountryData[...] returns a TimeSeries, but the TimeSeries doesn't know what to do with @"DatePath".

Answer (score 1):

In the output of WolframAlpha click on the plus sign in the pod with the plot and select `Computable data`

```
data = {#[[1, 1]], 
     QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]} & /@ (WolframAlpha[
      "US population", {{"LongTermHistory:Population:CountryData", 1}, 
       "ComputableData"}, 
      PodStates -> {"LongTermHistory:Population:CountryData__Show \
projections", "LongTermHistory:Population:CountryData__Linear scale"}][[1]]);

ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you figure out what string arguments to use in that code?

Comment: It is pasted into the notebook when you select Computable data from the pod.