# How to get the population of Maryland for all years Wolfram has data on?

Tags: curated-data

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153200/how-to-get-the-us-population-for-every-year-wolfram-has-data-on?noredirect=1#comment409002_153200) I learned that I can get the US population for every year that Wolfram has data on using the following:

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Population", All}]
```

Next I wanted to find the population of Maryland for every year Wolfram has data on. The closest I can get is the following:

[image: AdministrativeDivisionData]

I tried the obvious approach, and got the following:

[image: AdministrativeDivisionData fails]

Wolfram-Alpha made a plot with data going back over 200 years, so Wolfram clearly has more than just the latest population. So how can I get a result for Maryland population that is similar to what I get from CountryData above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple function does the job

```
pop[state_] :=
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {state, "UnitedStates"}][
   EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
    "Population", {"Date" -> All}]]["Path"]
```

Now for example

```
DateListPlot[pop["Utah"] /. Quantity[a_, __] :> a/10^6.,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 Filling -> Bottom,
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or

```
pop["Utah"] /. {a_, Quantity[b_, __]} :> {First@DateList@a, 
    PaddedForm[b/10^6., {3, 2}]} // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Entity[...]["Path"] returns the dates in strange units, but the dates are useful if I use    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Maryland", "UnitedStates"}][
   EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
    "Population", {"Date" -> All}]][
  "Path"] /. {date_, pop_} :> {First@DateList@date, pop}

Comment: Love the part about converting the graphic in WA into TimeSeriesData.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [free-form input](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153130/731) to find this information:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And similarly, with inline free-form input:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can inspect the entities involved to see how we could have specified it using code:

[image: Mathematica graphics]